# Function isn't returning the uint256 value after initializing mapping

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping, function, smart-contract

I'm  facing a problem with the function return type in solidity. Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Birth {
    mapping(uint256 => bool) public isValidBirthCerti;

    function birthCertiGenerator(
        string memory _Name

    ) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 birthCerti = uint256(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    _Name
                )
            )
        ) % 100000000000000000;
        isValidBirthCerti[birthCerti] = true; //if I remove this ,then I get the returned value.
        return birthCerti;
    }
}
```

In the **birthCertiGenerator** function which returns a **uint256** type value, is not returning the value if I use `isValidBirthCerti[birthCerti] = true;` this line.
Is there anything wrong ? Or Am I missing something here?

Comment: ``` mapping(uint256 => bool) public isValidBirthCerti;``` is a mapping , not a modifier. @alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to call the birthCertiGenerator from ethers.js or web3 is normal that you don't receive the unit256 as adding  `isValidBirthCerti[birthCerti] = true;` you are changing the state, and this your method is a transaction, not a view/pure any more.

Hope it helps

Comment: so state changing function dosen't return anything ? Thats the point?

Comment: When calling outside the blockchain they return the transaction receipt